# Design - Parser.hasInfo(MyClass) vs MyClass.hasInfo()

Tags: java, design, class-design

I'm working on a document processing system.

I feel confident with a `Document` class which represents each document being processed.

**The issue:**

Each `Document` *can* have a `CoverSheet`, and if it does, we need to get `CoverSheetInfo` from this `CoverSheet` (for renaming and processing). But checking for a `CoverSheet` and coercing the info into `CoverSheetInfo` involves a fair amount of Apache PDFBox code.

I'm trying to decide on the best place to have this functionality.

**Option 1**

`Document` class will have these methods:

`public boolean hasCoverSheet()`

`public CoverSheetInfo getCoverSheetInfo()`

Pros:

Behavior is close to the data -- the process of checking a `Document` for a `CoverSheet` takes place in `Document` which seems sensible.

Cons:

This adds a lot of PDFBox - related parsing lines which make the other-wise simple set-get `Document` look cluttered and makes the `Document` class exceed 300 lines to include this functionality. Thus Option 2...

**Option 2**

Create a `DocumentParser` class which would have:

`public boolean hasCoverSheet(Document document)`

`public CoverSheetInfo getCoverSheetInfo(Document document)`

Pros:

All the PDFBox - specific parsing code is in it's own Class. I think this is a good example of enforcing Single Responsibility/Law of Demeter As I don't think `Document` should necessarily know how to parse information from cover sheets.

Cons:

Awkward(?) separation of behavior from data(?)

Which one seems most reasonable and how so?

**Edit:** I'm desperate. Any feed back would be absolutely. fricken. loved.

**Edit 2**

A `Document` is in this case a scanned mortgage document, and it will *always* be a PDF. A `Document` is created when my app finds files in a directory (one `Document` is made for each file found). `DocumentParser` should process `Documents`, right, File was a typo.

At this point, `Document` is just a wrapper around the File essentially. In **Option 1**, it would have `CoverSheetInfo` as a field and `File stubFile` as well as `boolean` regarding the existence of these things.

Here's the "story" for what I'm doing:

Someone will scan a document. It will end up in a directory. My app needs to look at that directory, and

1. rename the files by their cover sheet (if they have one)
2. make a stub out of the first 8 pages (if the file is very large)
3. Upload these files (and any stubs made) to Google Drive.

Comment: Is checking a `Document` for the _existence_ of a `CoverSheet` an expensive operation? Or is just retrieving the full `CoverSheetInfo` the expensive part?

Comment: Does this breakdown make any sense at all? https://www.dropbox.com/s/zyfnmh1yva56o2t/mmcrae-classes.txt?dl=0 (I'm primarily a C# & JavaScript guy, so that tentative design might not work at all in the Java world... if it even makes sense in my .NET world...)

Comment: @TroyGizzi that's actually super similar to what I had going on in the **Option 1** situation, but your idea of private constructor for `CoverSheetInfo` and `StubInfo` are different/interesting. 

One thing on my mind about this though: I feel like it's a bad(ish) thing to have references to specific classes (`CoverSheetInfo` and `StubInfo` in this case) set in `Document`'s class i.e. I feel it's best to have those things passed into a constructor -- at least that's something discussed in Dependency Injection but maybe that doesn't quite apply here... Thanks a bunch for your feedback

Comment: Ah, DI, now I get what you meant by your "CoverSheet and Stub are not part of the constructor" comment in your other post. In C#, we often pass Interfaces as constructor parameters to provide DI. Makes sense that would probably be a common approach in Java as well. -- And shame on me for not getting what you meant right away, especially since I suggested a DI solution to another recent question here. :-)

Comment: I think answering your question requires a little bit more information. What is a Document and what kind of information it holds? Are all Documents PDF documents? How a Document object gets created? Why the DocumentParser processes Files, not Documents? (Option 2 seems a safer choice. At least it decouples a third party library from an entity.)

Comment: @COMEFROM checkout my last edit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I understood,  the cover page is an important property of a document in your application. Then I'd represent it with a getter. The business classes dealing with renaming the document then only need the `Document` object and have no dependency to a parser which they do not care about.

How that getter is implemented is a different question. You could for example provide a mock implementation that provides a pre-defined cover page for unit testing. To solve the problem of a long class with multiple responsibilities, you could extract the parsing code to a separate class that is used by the real `Document` implementation.

To go one step further, the parser instance could be provided to the `Document` constructor. That's called dependency injection and decoples the parser from the document, so that other parsers could be used. For exapmle, the unit test of `Document` can use a mock implementation of the parser. There are frameworks like [weld](http://weld.cdi-spec.org/) which essentially provide a factory to create classes without knowing the exact dependency (i.e. the parser).

Comment: I know it's been a while... but I came back to this issue again today and so I checked here. I appreciate / understand your first paragraph. That makes sense to me... a `Coversheet` is an important part of a `Document`. But you lost me in the second paragraph... are you suggesting I pass in a Parser object to `Document` constructor, and then use that Parser in `Document.get...`? If I'm passing a Parser it makes me think I might as well use the Parser. Does your 2nd paragraph contradict your first?

Comment: @mmcrae: Yes, that's called dependency injection. Note that only the one who *creates* a document has to know the parser, not the one *using* it. But you you don't need to use DI if you think it's overkill - my suggestions on the model go on their own. I extracted the DI part into a new paragraph. Did that make it clear?

Answer (score 2):

Why not have a separate `CoverSheet` object? Then you can cleanly do

```
CoverSheetInfo coverInfo = null;
if(theDocument.hasCoverSheet()) {
    CoverSheet cover = theDocument.getCoverSheet();
    coverInfo = cover.getInfo();
}
```

Sorry, I'm not familiar with PDFBox, so I don't know if this introduces more complexity than it solves, but (IMHO) it's a much cleaner design.